# Footer has a white space to the right

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically, as you will see, when i preview the device in mobile S, the footer does not fill the entire browser width unlike the nav bar. This problem is happening from mobile S size to laptop L size!
The code in jsFiddle is more complete!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jasya.jpg
How can i get rid of this white space?

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/84td5z1x/

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('.ulSecções');
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.ulSecções li');

  //Toggle Nav
  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('navActive');

    //Animate Links
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if (link.style.animation) {
        link.style.animation = '';
      } else {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.5}s`;
      }
    });

    //Burger Animation
    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
  });


}

navSlide();
```

```css
/*Ignore this*/

div.whiteSpace {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}


/*Mobile navBar Burger*/

.burger {
  display: none;
  float: right;
  padding: 31px 49px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
  width: 27px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(192, 163, 68);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  border-radius: 2px;
}


/*Background Menu*/

nav.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 16px 3px;
}


/*Costumização do body */

body {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

body .menu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
}


/*Costumização logo */

.ulLogo li {
  list-style: none;
}

.ulLogo li a img {
  width: 180px;
  float: left;
  padding: 19px 0px 0px 60px;
}


/*Transição Logo Opacity*/

.ulLogo li a img#espiral:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: opacity 300ms linear 0s;
}

.ulLogo li a img#espiral:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 399ms linear 0s;
}


/*Costumização sections */

nav .ulSecções {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 90px;
}

nav ul.ulSecções li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 90px;
}

nav ul.ulSecções li a {
  display: block;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", "Palatino", sans-serif;
  color: rgb(192, 163, 68);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  opacity: 0.9;
  padding: 0px 18px;
}

nav ul.ulSecções li a i {
  font-size: 16px;
}

nav ul.ulSecções li a.loja {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}


/*Footer*/

body footer div.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 170px;
  background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
}

footer div.icons {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px 0px;
}

body footer div.icons ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

body footer div.icons ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
}

body footer div.icons ul li a {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 28px;
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}


/*Toggle burger*/

.toggle .line1 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}

.toggle .line2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggle .line3 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
}


/*Mobile screen adjustments*/


/*Mobile S*/

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  nav.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 140px;
  }
  .ulLogo li {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .ulLogo li a img {
    width: 400px;
  }
  .ulSecções {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 40vh;
    top: 139px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 400ms ease-out 0s;
  }
  nav ul.ulSecções li a {
    display: block;
    font-family: "Ubuntu", "Palatino", sans-serif;
    color: rgb(192, 163, 68);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 0px 10px;
  }
  nav ul.ulSecções li a.loja {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  nav ul.ulSecções li a i {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  div.burger {
    display: block;
    padding-right: 100px;
    padding-top: 57px;
  }
  .burger div {
    width: 40px;
    height: 5px;
    margin: 4px;
  }
  /*Footer*/
  body footer div.footer {
    width: 100%;
    /*Erro aqui!!*/
    height: 250px;
    background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
  }
  body footer div.icons ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 15px 30px;
  }
  body footer div.icons ul li a {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}

.navActive {
  transform: translateX(0%)
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="menu">
    <div>
      <ul class="ulLogo">
        <li title="Logo Carla Ornelas">
          <a href="#"><img id="espiral" src="../Logo.png"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="ulSecções">
        <li> <a href="../Main page/index.html" title="Home">Home</a> </li>
        <li class="carla"> <a class="carlaOrnelas" href="#" title="Carla Ornelas">Carla Ornelas</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Cursos">Cursos</a>
        </li>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Conteudos Especiais">Conteúdos Especiais</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Conteudos Especiais">Recursos</a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a href="" title="Contatos">Contatos</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="" title="Acesse a nosa loja" <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="burger">
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
      <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="whiteSpace"></div>
<!--Footer-->
<footer>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="icons">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/carlaornelasoficial" target="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/byCarlaOrnelasoficial" target="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCa8V607fOSo9tu2AT0y137w" target="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"> </i> </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `body {margin: 0;}` to reset default margin.

Comment: Did it alredy on my source code, idk why but i forgot to put it in fiddle my bad. But no, it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Are you sure? Answer from maymun should work. Have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/oq8mtk10/

Comment: @brckner Yes I'm sure, i don't have a problem with that width. I've reseted the body margin long ago! I don't have the problem at laptop width, i have it when i inspect on mobile S to tablet width.

Comment: Then i do not understand the problem. With ``` body { margin: 0;} ```, i inspected it on chrome devtools with several devices and on my machine its fine. Can you post some screenshots, maybe i'am missing something here.

Comment: @brckner Sure! Here: https://imgur.com/TqF8btS  https://imgur.com/V1vOt2n  https://imgur.com/NJTtdmF , as you can see in the last print, the white space is not there, the size of that print is laptop L, for me is the size of my screen.

Comment: Hmmm, i don't know ... maybe set the body margin outside the media query and try to inspect the footer tag and div.footer. Maybe it is something wrong there with sizing. What happens when you inspect the footer elements or the whitespace? which element is responsible for it?

Comment: @brckner Here, if I inspect the white space: https://imgur.com/cTkY1Oq

Comment: Why do you have that class (fa-event-icons-ready) on the html tag? Try to remove it and see if it causes the problem.

Comment: @brckner i don't know why if I go to my main code, the html class is not fa-event-icons-ready

Comment: But no, i've removed and it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your CSS, add.

```
*{
  margin: 0;
}
```

This should remove the pre-existing margin, that is present by default on browsers.

I always start my css with

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Know more about [**the CSS universal selector (*)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors)

Comment: I have it alredy on my style.css, it isn't in the code snippet, but it is on my main code. It does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The body is set to margin 8px, set it to 0. The above answer is correct.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/93WkW.jpg

Comment: No it isn't sir, i've alredy done all of that, see: https://imgur.com/x1L46QQ , it does not solve my problem as you can see: https://imgur.com/9N7Lh2z

Comment: In the print you sent me, there may be a scroll bar in the x axis, if you scroll it you will se the white space.